# PyQt4 .deleteLater() with lists of objects

Tags: python, pyqt4

So I'm currently writing a minesweeper GUI using PyQt4 with Python 3.4. Everything is coming pretty easily except I cannot create a new game. So here's how my program is designed:

I have a main file that just creates a Ui_MainWindow I created in the Qt designer. In that Ui_MainWindow class, I create an instance of the Board class. The Board class basically is the controller of all the gameplay. In this Board class, I have a for loop that creates the buttons on the frame. The buttons are actually instances of the Cell class in an lists (example [Cell[0], Cell[1], etc...]. The Cell class inherits from the QPushButton class so that I can create signals for mouse buttons.

Everything works very well except I cannot start a new game. When the users says start a new game, the Board class is supposed to delete all the buttons and redraw the board. It deletes all of the buttons but does not redraw the Board. I may know what is causing this but none of my test seem to prove my hypothesis.

Here's what I think occurs:

Because I keep up with my cells in an 2D list, when I call the .deleteLater() (which only schedules the deletion) it deletes the new Cell class instance because I tell Python to delete the widget associated with that list element. (example array[row][col].deleteLater ... cells = [] ... cells[row].append(Cell(...))

Here's all of my code if what I said above makes no sense:

Main.py

```js
from Main_Window import Ui_MainWindow, QtGui
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
            
    # Create GUI application
    application = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)    
    window = Ui_MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

Main_Window.py

```js
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file '..\UI\Main_Window.ui'
#
# Created: Mon Jan 12 01:04:45 2015
#      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from Board import *
try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(0, 0)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.horizontalLayout_1 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_1"))
        spacerItem = QtGui.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_1.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.verticalLayout_1 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_1"))
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_2"))
        self.minesLCD = QtGui.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.minesLCD.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.minesLCD.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.minesLCD.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(90, 32))
        self.minesLCD.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("minesLCD"))
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.minesLCD)
        spacerItem1 = QtGui.QSpacerItem(30, 30, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(32, 32))
        self.pushButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(32, 32))
        self.pushButton.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        spacerItem2 = QtGui.QSpacerItem(30, 30, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem2)
        self.timeLCD = QtGui.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.timeLCD.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.timeLCD.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.timeLCD.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(90, 32))
        self.timeLCD.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.Box)
        self.timeLCD.setLineWidth(1)
        self.timeLCD.setMidLineWidth(0)
        self.timeLCD.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("timeLCD"))
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.timeLCD)
        self.verticalLayout_1.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        spacerItem3 = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 20, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        self.verticalLayout_1.addItem(spacerItem3)
        self.gridFrame = QtGui.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridFrame.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(272, 272))
        self.gridFrame.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.gridFrame.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)
        self.gridFrame.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridFrame"))
        self.verticalLayout_1.addWidget(self.gridFrame)
        spacerItem4 = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout_1.addItem(spacerItem4)
        self.horizontalLayout_1.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_1)
        spacerItem5 = QtGui.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_1.addItem(spacerItem5)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 620, 31))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        self.menuFile = QtGui.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menuFile"))
        self.menuHelp = QtGui.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuHelp.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menuHelp"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionNew = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionNew.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionNew"))
        self.actionLeaderboards = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionLeaderboards.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionLeaderboards"))
        self.actionDifficulty = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionDifficulty.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionDifficulty"))
        self.actionSettings = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSettings.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionSettings"))
        self.actionTips = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionTips.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionTips"))
        self.actionHow_To_Play = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionHow_To_Play.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionHow_To_Play"))
        self.actionReadMe = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionReadMe.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionReadMe"))
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionNew)
        self.menuFile.addSeparator()
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionLeaderboards)
        self.menuFile.addSeparator()
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionDifficulty)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionSettings)
        self.menuFile.addSeparator()
        self.menuHelp.addAction(self.actionTips)
        self.menuHelp.addAction(self.actionHow_To_Play)
        self.menuHelp.addAction(self.actionReadMe)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuHelp.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.board = Board(self.gridFrame, self.minesLCD, self.timeLCD, self.pushButton, [spacerItem1, spacerItem2])

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Minesweeper", None))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File", None))
        self.menuHelp.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Help", None))
        self.actionNew.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New", None))
        self.actionLeaderboards.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Leaderboards", None))
        self.actionDifficulty.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Difficulty", None))
        self.actionSettings.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Settings", None))
        self.actionTips.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Tips", None))
        self.actionHow_To_Play.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "How To Play", None))
        self.actionReadMe.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ReadMe", None))
```

Functions.py

```js
import configparser as cfg
import winsound as win
import random, sys, wave

def play_sound(file):

    win.PlaySound(file, win.SND_ASYNC)
    
def save(file, settings):
    """Saves new default settings"""
    configParser = cfg.RawConfigParser() # Get parser
    
    # Set each attribute
    configParser.add_section("info")
    configParser.set("info", "default", settings[0])
    configParser.set("info", "color", str(settings[1]))
    configParser.set("info", "sound", str(settings[2]))
    configParser.set("info", "question", str(settings[3]))

    # Write data to file
    with open(file, 'wb') as configFile:
        configParser.write(configFile)    
        
def defaults(file):
    """Reads the default settings from a cfg file"""
    configParser = cfg.RawConfigParser() # Get parser
    configParser.read(file) # Parse file
    
    # Get each attribute  
    default = configParser.get("info", "default")
    color = configParser.getboolean("info", "color")
    sound = configParser.getboolean("info", "sound")
    question = configParser.getboolean("info", "question")
    
    # Change format if the default is custom
    if default == "custom":
        sizex = configParser.getint("custom", "sizex")
        sizey = configParser.getint("custom", "sizey")
        mines = configParser.getint("custom", "mines")
            
        default = [sizex,sizey,mines]
    
    return [default, color, sound, question] # Return list of values
    
def generate_array(sizex, sizey, mines):
    """Generates an array of the minesweeper board"""
    array = []
    
    # Create array with given dimensions
    for i in range(sizex):
        array.append([])
        for j in range(sizey):
            array[i].append(0)
            
    coords = []
    
    # Add mines to board array
    for amt in range(mines):
        while True:
            # Set index for mine
            x = random.randint(0, sizex-1)
            y = random.randint(0, sizey-1)
            
            # Add 1 to each surrounding coordinates if the index is not already a mine
            if [x,y] not in coords:
                array[x][y] = -1 # -1 is the number for a mine
                coords.append([x,y]) # Add index to list of coordinates
                # Note: second/third arguments in some if statements guards against negative indexing
                try:
                    if array[x-1][y-1] != -1 and x != 0 and y != 0:
                        array[x-1][y-1] += 1
                except:
                    pass
                try:
                    if array[x+1][y+1] != -1:
                        array[x+1][y+1] += 1
                except:
                    pass
                try:
                    if array[x-1][y+1] != -1 and x != 0:
                        array[x-1][y+1] += 1
                except:
                    pass
                try:
                    if array[x+1][y-1] != -1 and y != 0:
                        array[x+1][y-1] += 1
                except:
                    pass
                try:
                    if array[x-1][y] != -1 and x != 0:
                        array[x-1][y] += 1
                except:
                    pass
                try:
                    if array[x+1][y] != -1:
                        array[x+1][y] += 1
                except:
                    pass
                try:
                    if array[x][y-1] != -1 and y != 0:
                        array[x][y-1] += 1
                except:
                    pass
                try:
                    if array[x][y+1] != -1:
                        array[x][y+1] += 1
                except:
                    pass
                break
        
    return(array)
```

Board.py

```js
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from Cell import *
import Functions as fn

class Board:
    
    def __init__(self, frame, mineCounter, timeCounter, face, spacers):
        """Class for gameplay board"""
        # Save passed in variables
        self.frame = frame
        self.mineCounter = mineCounter
        self.timeCounter = timeCounter
        self.face = face
        self.spacers = spacers
        
        # Get default settings
        self.settings = fn.defaults("..\\Settings\default.cfg")
        self.difficultyTable = {"easy": [9,9,10], "intermediate": [16,16,40], "expert": [16,30,99]}
        
        # Set initial difficulty
        try:
            self.difficulty = self.difficultyTable[self.settings[0]]
        except:
            self.difficulty = self.settings[0]
            self.settings[0] = "custom"
            
        # Declare other variables variables
        self.face.clicked.connect(lambda: self.newGame(True))
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.tick)
        self.time = 0
        self.remaining = 0
        self.mines = 0
        self.array = []
        
        self.newGame()
    
    def clear(self):
        """Deletes all buttons from frame"""
        for row in range(self.difficulty[0]):
            for col in range(self.difficulty[1]):
                self.cells[row][col].deleteLater()
    
    def newGame(self, clear=False):
        """Start a new game"""
        # Clears the current frame
        if clear:
            self.clear()
            
        # Reset Variables
        self.cells = []
        self.array = fn.generate_array(self.difficulty[0], self.difficulty[1], self.difficulty[2])
        self.mines = self.difficulty[2]
        self.remaining = self.difficulty[0] * self.difficulty[1] - self.difficulty[2]
        self.time = 0
        self.face.setText(":)")        
        
        # Start Counters
        self.mineCounter.display(self.mines)
        self.timeCounter.display(self.time)

        # Resize GUI aspects
        self.frame.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(self.difficulty[1]*32+2, self.difficulty[0]*32+2))
        self.spacers[0].changeSize(32+(self.difficulty[1]-9)*16.25, 32)
        self.spacers[1].changeSize(32+(self.difficulty[1]-9)*16.25, 32)
       
        # Create list of cells
        for row in range(self.difficulty[0]):
            self.cells.append([])
            for col in range(self.difficulty[1]):
                self.cells[row].append(Cell(self.frame, QtCore.QRect(col*32, row*32, 34, 34), self.array[row][col], self.settings[1], self.settings[3]))
                self.cells[row][col].leftClicked.connect(lambda boolean=True, x=row, y=col: self.show(x, y, boolean))
                self.cells[row][col].rightClicked.connect(lambda boolean=True, x=row, y=col: self.flag(x, y))
                self.cells[row][col].Clicked.connect(lambda: self.face.setText(":o"))
                
    def setMode_difficulty(self, difficulty):
        """Sets game difficulty"""
        self.clear() # Remove old buttons
        
        try:
            self.difficulty = self.difficultyTable[difficulty]
            self.settings[0] = difficulty
        except:
            self.difficulty = difficulty
            self.settings[0] = "custom"
            
        self.newGame(True)
        
    def setMode_graphics(self, value):
        """Sets graphics to true or false"""
        self.settings[1] = value
        
        for row in range(self.difficulty[0]):
            for col in range(self.difficulty[1]):
                self.cells[row][col].setColor(value)
        
    def setMode_sound(self, value):
        """Sets sound to true or false"""
        self.settings[2] = value
        
    def setMode_question(self, value):
        """Sets question to true or false"""
        self.settings[3] = value
        
        for row in range(self.difficulty[0]):
            for col in range(self.difficulty[1]):
                self.cells[row][col].setQuestion(value)

    def tick(self):
        """Add 1 second to the timer"""
        # Timer maxes out at 999
        if self.time != 999:
            self.time += 1
            self.timeCounter.display(self.time)
        
    def endGame(self, win):
        """Stops the current game"""
        self.timer.stop()
        
        # Play the game ending sound
        if self.settings[2]:
            if win:
                fn.play_sound("..\\Sounds\\Complete_Sound.wav")
            else:
                fn.play_sound("..\\Sounds\\Wrong_Sound.wav")
                
        # Disable signal for all buttons and set the coordinate to a flag if the player has won
        for row in range(self.difficulty[0]):
            for col in range(self.difficulty[1]):
                self.cells[row][col].setSignal(False)
                if self.array[row][col] == -1 and win:
                    self.cells[row][col].setDisplay("<|")
    
    def showAll(self):
        """Reveals all mine cells"""
        for row in range(self.difficulty[0]):
            for col in range(self.difficulty[1]):
                self.cells[row][col].reveal(True) # Reveals a mine
    
    def flag(self, row, col):
        """Flags coordinate"""
        self.face.setText(":)")
        # Set the mine display to the correct number
        check = self.cells[row][col].flag()
        self.mines += check
        self.mineCounter.display(self.mines)
        
        if self.settings[2]:
            fn.play_sound("..\\Sounds\\Flag_Sound.wav")
        
    def check(self):
        """Checks to see if the player has won"""
        if self.remaining == 0:
            self.face.setText("8)")
            self.mineCounter.display(0)
            self.endGame(True)
            
    def show(self, row, col, mode=True):
        """Reveals coordinate"""
        check = True
        
        if mode:
            self.face.setText(":)")
        
        if not(self.timer.isActive()):

            # First move is always a useful click
            while self.array[row][col] == -1:
                self.array = fn.generate_array(self.difficulty[0], self.difficulty[1], self.difficulty[2]) # Generate new array

                # Change the number of each cell
                if self.array[row][col] != -1:
                    for ind1 in range(self.difficulty[0]):
                        for ind2 in range(self.difficulty[1]):
                            self.cells[ind1][ind2].setNumber(self.array[ind1][ind2])
                    
                  
            self.timer.start(1000) # Start timer if it is the first move

        # Determine the number of the coordinate and set that coordinate as clicked
        if self.array[row][col] > 0 and not(self.cells[row][col].flagged) and not(self.cells[row][col].questioned):
            self.array[row][col] = None
            self.cells[row][col].reveal()
            self.remaining -= 1
            self.check()
        elif self.array[row][col] == 0 and not(self.cells[row][col].flagged) and not(self.cells[row][col].questioned):
            self.array[row][col] = None
            self.cells[row][col].reveal()
            self.remaining -= 1
            self.showEmpty(row, col) # Reveals surrounding empty spaces
            self.check() 
        elif not(self.cells[row][col].flagged) and not(self.cells[row][col].questioned):
            self.face.setText("x(")
            self.showAll() # Reveals all mine locations
            self.endGame(False)
        else:
            check = False
            
        # The sound is only played if it is not being called recursively, the game is not over, and its not a flag
        if mode and check and self.settings[2] and self.timer.isActive():
            fn.play_sound("..\\Sounds\\Correct_Sound.wav")
        
    def showEmpty(self, row, col):
        """Reveals surrounding empty coordinates"""
        # Recursively check each surrounding coordinate and reveal if it equals 0
        # Note: second/third arguments in some if statements guards against negative indexing
        try:
            if self.array[row-1][col-1] >= 0 and row != 0 and col != 0:
                self.show(row-1, col-1, False)
        except:
            pass
        try:
            if self.array[row+1][col+1] >= 0:
                self.show(row+1, col+1, False)
        except:
            pass
        try:
            if self.array[row-1][col+1] >= 0 and row != 0:
                self.show(row-1, col+1, False)
        except:
            pass
        try:
            if self.array[row+1][col-1] >= 0 and col != 0:
                self.show(row+1, col-1, False)
        except:
            pass
        try:
            if self.array[row-1][col] >= 0 and row != 0:
                self.show(row-1, col, False)
        except:
            pass
        try:
            if self.array[row+1][col] >= 0:
                self.show(row+1, col, False)
        except:
            pass
        try:
            if self.array[row][col-1] >= 0 and col != 0:
                self.show(row, col-1, False)          
        except:
            pass
        try:
            if self.array[row][col+1] >= 0:
                self.show(row, col+1, False)
        except:
            pass
```

Cell.py

```js
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

colorTable = {"": "black", "1": "blue", "2": "green", "3": "red", "4": "navy", "5": "brown", "6": "teal", "7": "black", "8": "grey", "?": "black", "<|": "black", "x": "red", "*": "black"}

class Cell(QtGui.QPushButton):
    
    # Create signals
    leftClicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    rightClicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    Clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    
    def __init__(self, parent, geometry, number, color=False, mode=False):
        """Class for a cell"""
        # Save passed in variables
        self.number = number
        self.color = color
        self.mode = mode
        
        # Set initial flagging states
        self.flagged = False
        self.questioned = False

        # Inherit from QPushButton  
        QtGui.QPushButton.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setGeometry(geometry)      
    
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        """Defines event handler for mouse button press"""
        self.Clicked.emit() # Emit signal
        
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        """Defines event handler for mouse button release"""
        QtGui.QPushButton.mousePressEvent(self, event) # Get event handler
        
        # Determinate which button was pressed and emit that signal
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.leftClicked.emit()
        elif event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            self.rightClicked.emit()
    
    def flag(self):
        """Flags the cell"""
        # Determine value to return
        if self.mode:
            if self.flagged:
                self.flagged = False
                self.questioned = True
                self.setDisplay("?")
                value = 1
            elif self.questioned:
                self.questioned = False
                self.setDisplay("")
                value = 0
            else:
                self.flagged = True
                self.setDisplay("<|")
                value = -1
        else:
            if self.flagged:
                self.flagged = False
                self.setDisplay("")
                value = 1
            else:
                self.flagged = True
                self.setDisplay("<|")
                value = -1
                
        return value

        
    def reveal(self, mine=False):
        """Reveals the cell"""
        # Reveal a mine or wrong flag location
        if mine:
            if self.flagged and self.number != -1:
                self.setDisplay("x")
                self.setClick(False)
            elif not(self.flagged) and self.number == -1:
                self.setDisplay("*")
                self.setClick(False)
            else:
                self.setSignal(False)
                    
        # Reveal a non-mine location
        else:
            if not(self.flagged) and not(self.questioned):
                if self.number != 0:
                    self.setDisplay(str(self.number))
                else:
                    self.setText("")
        
                self.setClick(False)
    
    def setDisplay(self, string):
        """Sets button text"""
        self.setText(string)
        
        if self.color:
            self.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {color: " + colorTable[string] + "}")
            
    def setClick(self, value1):
        """Sets the button click status"""
        self.setEnabled(value1)
        
    def setSignal(self, value):
        """Sets the singal sending status"""
        self.blockSignals(True)
    
    def setNumber(self, number):
        """Sets button number"""
        self.number = number
```

NOTE: Obviously my main window is not complete.